# Nginx 404 to 301 redirect based on URI

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, nginx

I am trying to create a multiple 404 redirects in WordPress, and I am currently using this:

```
error_page 404 @foobar;

location @foobar {
    rewrite  .* / permanent;
}
```

I know this is meant for a redirect to the homepage, but ***this method is not working at all***, for it defaults to the regular WordPress 404.php file that is included with the theme.  That is fine, but I need to get the redirect working via Nginx instead of WP because I need to create different redirects once a page has been declared a 404.

Example:
Say I have about 10 categories on my WP Site.
I have posts that come and go, and once a post is gone, I would like to redirect that post (because each post in a certain category has a unique identifier) to the base category.

Example: redirect non existent post

```
/i-love-soup-cause-it-tastes-so-good-campbellssoup ---> /category/campbellssoup
```

or

`/toystory-3-is-a-great-movie-coolmovies ---> /category/coolmovies`

Basically I need to create multiple redirects to multiple locations ONLY AFTER the URI has been established as a 404.  Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Ok, using

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```

I managed to take the virtual errors out of wordpress.  Now I have the redirect to `@foobar` working, but I am unable to get the uri's to transfer to the `@foobar` location block.  I am guessing it is something to do with my try_files in my / location block.

```
location / {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: you can't do a 404 and 301 at the same time, it's either this or that

Comment: I want to catch the 404, and bring all 404's into their own location block so I can handle the redirects based on URI. Maybe its easier said than done, but that would solve this directly without the use of plugins.

Comment: how about you send all the 404's to a php script and that script generates it's 404, would that work for u ?

Comment: It would work, but I have the 404 location block working, I just can't get the rewrites to work as I can't get the syntax correct.  I have the wordpress default 404.php for its template, but I would rather have all old posts get redirected to the category they once belonged too.

Answer (score 0):

First there is a syntax error in your config, it should be `error_page 404 = @fallback`.
This should work fine, **but** only if wordpress is generating a 404. My guess is it is including something like 404.php instead. I'm also not sure if you can change the status code within a named location. The documentation explicitly notes that a fallback location can be used, in the case where the URI does not need to be changed and provides changing the URL using a different syntax that is of no use to you.
I would first figure out if WordPress is handling the 404 by itself. If that's the case, then handle the redirect in that file.
If it is not, then simply create your own page that handles the redirect in the scripting language you're comfortable with. If you can do rewrites in named locations for error pages, then the bottom part of @tcurvelo solution should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the input Melvyn, and I would "like" to handle the redirects via Nginx since it would be faster and there are only a few of them based on the amount of categories I have.  I have managed to get the 404 Redirect to work so it bypasses WP 404.php, and I have successfully made a 301 redirect in there to the homepage, but I am having a hard time retrieving the URI that came to the site with for the redirect.  The only thing I am using now is `redirect .* / permanent;` which will 301 successfully after 404, so I know I can do more if I had the URI picked up correctly.